# How to check isEmpty on Column Data Spark scala

Tags: sql, arrays, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

My data looks like :

```
[null,223433,WrappedArray(),null,460036382,0,home,home,home]
```

How do I check if the col3 is empty on query in spark sql ? I tried to explode but when I do that the empty array rows are disappearing. Can some suggest me a way to do this.

I tried :

```
val homeSet = result.withColumn("subscriptionProvider", explode($"subscriptionProvider"))
```

where `subscriptionProvider(WrappedArray())` is the column having array of values but some arrays can be empty. I need to get the subscriptionProvider with null values and subscriptionProvider array has "Comcast"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val tmp = df.withColumn("subscriptionProvider", 
  when(size($"subscriptionProvider") !== 0, $"subscriptionProvider").otherwise(array(lit(null).cast("string"))))

tmp.withColumn("subscriptionProvider", explode($"subscriptionProvider"))
```

Comment: Thank you. It works. But Is it efficient to do create 2 columns df.withColumn

Comment: But When I tried with : tmp.filter($"subscriptionProvider" === "null").collect.foreach(println)  its not working

Comment: tmp.filter($"requestId" === "223433").select($"subscriptionProvider").collect.foreach(println) gives [null] but when I query tmp.filter($"subscriptionProvider" === "null").collect.foreach(println)  its showing nothing

Answer (score 2):

LostInOverflow's answer is good for keeping in the dataframe mindset. However it depends on the size of your lists as to whether `size` is efficient. If you are going to have large lists, then dropping out and back into the dataframe might be best:

```
val dfSchema = df.schema
val filtered = df.rdd.filter(!_.getList[String](2).isEmpty)
sqlContext.createDataFrame(filtered, dfSchema)
```

Comment: I tried ur idea, but : val records = sqlContext.read.schema(schema).json(filePath)

val dfSchema = records.schema
val filtered = records.rdd.filter(!_.getList[String](0).isEmpty)
val newRecords = sqlContext.createDataFrame(filtered, dfSchema) newRecords.filter($"requestId" === "223433").collect.foreach(println) It gives me error

Comment: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to scala.collection.Seq

Comment: @Swetha You have to replace the 0 with the ordinal position of your column. I have edited my answer to be specific to your request

Answer (score 0):

> How to check isEmpty on Column Data Spark scala

```
size($"ArrayColumn") === 0
```